# this keyword error, please help

Tags: apex

i have a simple apex program and i am trying to execute it from "developer console" i am getting this error.

> "unexpected token: thisexample  at line 11"

```
public class thisexample {
  public integer age=10;
  public thisexample(integer age)
  {
    this.age=age;

    System.debug('the value of age is '+age);    
  }
}

thisexample t1=new thisexample(22);
t1.age;
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve by last line -- t1.age; ?

Comment: Hopefully you've resolved this issue now, like I said in my answer this code does work in the dev console. I'm going to close it because I don't think it's going to be of use to anyone else in the future.

Comment: This was apparently related to a specific syntax error, though the code in the question works aside from the last line which generates a different error to that stated. This is unlikely to ever be of use to anyone else.

Answer (score 2):

Please comment last line,

```
public class thisexample {
  public integer age=10;
  public thisexample(integer age)
  {
    this.age=age;

    System.debug('the value of age is '+age);    
  }
}

thisexample t1=new thisexample(22);
system.debug('Age #####'+t1.age);
```

Answer (score 1):

This code works perfectly fine in the console, though you must remove the last line because it causes a compilation error.

I suspect when you ran it and got the error you say you must have been missing a semicolon or brance somewhere, and above and beyond that the title of your question suggests that you tried to use `this` as a variable name which isn't allowed.

Answer (score -1):

try this:

thisexample t1=new thisexample(22);